# Error al cargar json

Tags: javascript, json, brackets

Que tal! Estoy usando una api llamada jQuery Mapael para la creación de mapas interactivos en html, estoy cargando los datos de un json a la aplicación, he aquí el código:

```
$(function () {
        $(".mapcontainer span").html("Loading JSON data").css({"color":"blue", "font-weight":"bold"});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.getJSON("import_from_json_file.json", function (data) {
                //Codigo bla bla bla...
            }).fail(function() {
                // Error
                $(".mapcontainer span").html("Failed to load JSON data").css({"color":"red"});
            });
        }, 200);
    });
```

Sin embargo, el error me da al cargar el json, me arroja el error, ya hice lo siguiente para solucionarlo y nada

-Cambie "import_from_json_file.json" por './import_from_json_file.json'

-Puse la ruta completa el archivo, algo así: "C:/gatitos/cafeCargado/import_from_json_file.json"

-Validé el json en jasonlint

Leí que hay que configurar un web.config para que lo lea, pero no estoy añadiendo un servidor ni algo por el estilo, todo es local

Answer (score 0):

En vez de poner:

`C:/gatitos/cafeCargado/import_from_json_file.json`

Colaca adelante `file:///`, Te Quedaria asi:

`file:///C:/gatitos/cafeCargado/import_from_json_file.json`

Comment: Sigue igual, no ha dado resultado